# Domain/Subdomain cookie not set with Angular and ExpressJS

Tags: angular, express, cookies

OK. I give up and have to ask. I've read many articles and SO questions/answers and understand the idea, but I'm missing something.

#### The problem

**Client:** domain.com (Angular 14 site)
**Server:** auth.domain.com (ExpressJS, CORS setup)

- Client gets responses from Server endpoints no problem.
- Server endpoint (auth.domain.com/test) sends basic JSON response + sets cookie
- Client requests test endpoint, gets response, but **cookie is not set**
- When Client get response from Server, in the headers I see `set-cookie` header and all values/options correctly set
- Angular (custom interceptor listening for requests/responses) doesn't see `set-cookie` header
- Open Server (test endpoint) directly in browser, cookie is set... and now Client sees the cookie too!
- Everything works fine on `localhost`

#### Question

Why isn't the cookie set when Client requests the Server (subdomain) endpoint?

### The setup

Cookies are set like this:
`set-cookie: my-cookie-name=test-value; Max-Age=900000; HttpOnly; Secure; Domain=.domain.com; SameSite=Lax`

Options I've tried:

- `Domain=.domain.com`
- `Domain=domain.com`
- without `HttpOnly` and `Secure`

Headers are set like this in ExpressJS:
Note: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is currently is set to * just for testing at the moment.

```
app.use( function ( req, res, next ) {
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Content-Range, X-Requested-With' );
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' );
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true );
    next();
} );
```

Angular (Client) sends requests with `{ withCredentials: true }` option.

Comment: I think httpOnly means that javascript has no access to the cookie.

Comment: @MikeOne well, yes, and I want it set. Same as Secure. That's not the problem. Problem is that Client, even thought it is in the same domain, isn't setting the cookie from the endpoint.

Comment: I’m confused. You mean “the browser” is not setting the cookie..?

Comment: Generally, I want the user to be able to login using the Client (Angular) but the login request to be sent to the auth.domain.com server. When the response comes and user is logged in, I need to somehow save the auth cookie or jwt in order for next time for the Client to see get the cookie/jwt and re-authenticate ... But, right now, the user logs in, on server I authenticate, but client doesn't respond in anyway that user is logged in because it doesn't get the cookie.